# Creating Solr client using Solrj Api with Kerberized Solr

Tags: solr, kerberos, solrj

I am trying to create a solr client using solrj api for kerberised solr. And as per the documentation of [solrj](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/kerberos-authentication-plugin.html#KerberosAuthenticationPlugin-UsingSolrJwithaKerberizedSolr), it is required to set `HttpClientUtil.setConfigurer(new Krb5HttpClientConfigurer());` in code.

But the solrj api jar do not have the function `setConfigurer` inside the `HttpClientUtil` class. I am using the below dependency from maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Is it possible to create solr client using `new HttpSolrClient.Builder` and enable kerberisation to read the `jaas.config` file to do the authentication and authorization.

Currently i am creating the solr client like below;

```
new HttpSolrClient.Builder("solrUrlString").build()
```

But i do not see a option to enable `Krb5HttpClientConfigurer` in the above way

Comment: It's October 2019 and the Solr documentation at [https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/kerberos-authentication-plugin.html#using-solrj-with-a-kerberized-solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/kerberos-authentication-plugin.html#using-solrj-with-a-kerberized-solr) has still not been updated. That's really embarrassing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "HttpClientUtil.setConfigurer" method was depreciated from "solr-solrj" version 6.0.0 and finally removed from version 7.0.0 onwards.

But still the documentation of [solrj](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/kerberos-authentication-plugin.html#KerberosAuthenticationPlugin-UsingSolrJwithaKerberizedSolr) has not been updated with the new way to create the Kerberized Solr client.

Figured out the way to do it in version 7.0.0 onwards:

```
        Builder solrClientBuilder = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("https://<hostname>/solr/<collectionName>");
        Krb5HttpClientBuilder krbBuilder = new Krb5HttpClientBuilder();
        SolrHttpClientBuilder krb5HttpClientBuilder = krbBuilder.getHttpClientBuilder(java.util.Optional.empty());
        HttpClientUtil.setHttpClientBuilder(krb5HttpClientBuilder);
        ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, false);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientUtil.createClient(params);

        SolrClient client = solrClientBuilder.withHttpClient(httpClient).build();
```